# Not sure why I'm getting a "Bus error 10" with strtok/ EOF

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to read in every line from a txt document and tokenize each line into the specific data. However, I keep getting this error "Bus error 10" at the end of the loop. I'm not sure why this is happened, as the buffer char * has more than enough allocated memory.

```
void* Producer(void *arg)
{
    printf("\nEntered Producer\n");
    int i, item, index;

    index = (int)arg;

    FILE *f = fopen(bookorders, "r");
    char c = fgetc(f);
    int z =0;
    while (c!=EOF) {
        char * buffer = (char *)calloc(1000, 1);
        while (c!='\n') {
            *(buffer+z) = c;
            z++;
            c = fgetc(f);
        }
        char * rpr;

        char delim[2] = "|";

        char * title = strtok_r(buffer, delim, &rpr);
        title = title +1;
        int leng = (int)strlen(title);
        *(title+leng-1) = '\0';

        double cost = atof(strtok_r(NULL, delim, &rpr));

        int id = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, delim, &rpr));

        char * cat_name = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &rpr);

        c = fgetc(f);
        printf("%c\n", c);
        z = 0;
        *buffer = '\0';

        free(buffer);
    }

fclose(f);
return NULL;
}
```

I omitted my code on mutexes because this skeleton doesn't work to begin with; I figured to only add the pertinent code. Also does this error have anything to do with the EOF condition of the while loop?

Comment: Do you know at what line the error occurs?

Comment: The error occurs the first time I use strtok_r, where "char *title = strtok_r(buffer, delim, &rpr)"

Comment: It doesn't look like you null-terminated `buffer` before calling `strtok_r`.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. You need to store the result in an `int` object to be able to distinguish between a `EOF` and a valid character value (which is returned as an `unsigned char` value converted to `int`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a large number of things in your code that could be running off the end of the buffer or dereferencing a null pointer (which might cause Bus error). It's going to be shorter for me to rewrite your code than to list all the mistakes, so here goes:

```
char *buffer = malloc(1000);
if ( !buffer )
    return NULL;

FILE *f = fopen(bookorders, "r");
int c, z;

if ( f ) for (;;)
{
    for ( z = 0; z < 999 && (c = fgetc(f)) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++z )
        buffer[z] = c;

    if ( z == 0 && c == EOF )
        break;

    buffer[z] = 0;

    char const delim[] = "|";
    char *rpr;
    char *title = strtok_r(buffer, delim, &rpr);
    if ( title[0] )
    {
        ++title;
        title[strlen(title) - 1] = 0;
    }

// Would be better to use `strtod` and `strtol` here
    char *ptr = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &rpr);
    double cost = ptr ? atof(ptr) : 0;

    ptr = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &rpr);
    int id = ptr ? atoi(ptr) : 0;

    char * cat_name = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &rpr);

// If you want to do something with title, cost, id, cat_name, now's the chance
}

free(buffer);
fclose(f);
return NULL;
```

Comment: How do you reset buffer for each new line

Comment: You don't need to "reset" it, you just start again from the beginning (`z = 0`). It doesn't matter if there is junk in the buffer after the terminator (`buffer[z] = 0;`)

Answer (score 1):

Two things I notice:

```
char buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
```

You defined `buffer` as a single `char` instead of a pointer. It should be:

```
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
```

The second issue is you forgot to null-terminated `buffer`. The `strtok_r` function expects a valid C-style string which means it must be null-terminated. I think adding:

```
buffer[z] = '\0';
```

After the inner input loop should correct that.

**Edit:**

You are also leaking memory every time through the outer `while` loop. I see memory allocations but no calls to `free`.

**Edit 2:**

Regarding your edit, `fgetc()` returns an `int` and you should change your input variable `c` to an `int` to match so the EOF test will work correctly.

Comment: I changed malloc to char * buffer = calloc(1000, sizeof(char) and I still get the bus error 10

Comment: @AbhishekSaha: I updated my answer. I'm sure I haven't addressed every potential problem in your code. I suggest you step through your program in a debugger (or consider a complete rewrite like Matt McNabb's answer).